# HQL with join of many tables, what should return?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm going to execute a query with Hibernate on many tables, so I've created a method like:

```
public List<Tab1> getListTab1() {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    String hql = "FROM Tab1 t1 join t1.tab2 t2 join t2.tab3 t3";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    return query.list();
}
```

Inspecting the result with debugger it seems to be right.
So, I'm trying to iterate on the resultset like:

```
1. List<Tab1> listTab1 = dao.getListTab1();
2. for (Tab1 tab1 : listTab1) {
3.     Tab2 tab2 = tab1.getTab2();
4.  Tab3 tab3 = tab1.getTab3();
5. }
```

But I get a `ClassCastException` on line 2.

Why? What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
String hql = "Select t1 FROM Tab1 t1 join fetch t1.tab2 t2 join fetch t2.tab3 t3";
```

Comment: Wonderful, that's what I'm looking for... now I learned how it works. Thank you.